# MSdeploy skip particular file type

Tags: msdeploy

I am trying to skip a sub folder and certain file types while deploying a webapp. I tried the below

```
Test.deploy.cmd /T /M:test.noreply.com /
P:a /G:False "-skip:Directory="Config\\Testdata\\Resx" -skip:filePath,absolutePath="Config\\Testdata\\*.xml""
```

The above is not working for some reason, am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think below worked for me

```
-skip:file="Config\\Testdata\\.*\.xml"
```